# Синхронизация, джава

Tags: java, многопоточность, синхронизация

Есть следующий вопрос: **нужна ли синхронизация ресурса,используемых разными потоками, если происходит только чтение ресурса, сам ресурс никак не изменяется.** Вот написал на коленке небольшой пример.

```
public class Test {
static Thread t1;
static Thread t2;
static Thread t3;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    t1 = new Thread(new MyThread1());
    t2 = new Thread(new MyThread2());
    t3 = new Thread(new MyThread3());

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();

}

static class MyThread1 implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true) {
            Thread.State state = t3.getState();
            boolean isAlive = t3.isAlive();
            //исключаем призрачную возможность того, что вывод будет неправильным
            synchronized (System.out){
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - " + state);
            }
            if(!isAlive)
                return;
        }
    }
}

static class MyThread2 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true) {
            Thread.State state = t3.getState();
            boolean isAlive = t3.isAlive();
            //исключаем призрачную возможность того, что вывод будет неправильным
            synchronized (System.out){
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - " + state);
            }
            if(!isAlive)
                return;
        }
    }
}
static class MyThread3 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        int count = 0;
        while(true){
            try{
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(200);
                if(count > 15)
                    break;
                count++;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

В данном коде общим ресурсом является

```
static Thread t3;
```

В потоках t1 и t2 мы проверяем состояние потока t3

```
Thread.State state = t3.getState();
boolean isAlive = t3.isAlive();
```

Может ли тут пойти что-то не так. Допустим 2 потока t1 и t2 попробуют одновременно получить доступ к методу getState(). Если тут все-таки нужна синхронизация, то объясните почему так и что конкретно может пойти не так.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.isAlive()` можно спокойно вызывать без синхронизации. А вот `Thread.getState()` не обеспечивает соблюдения *happens before*, поэтому потоки t1 и t2 без использования синхронизации могут не заметить изменения состояния потока t3.